# Trying to let all plots appear when running an R file in Rstudio

Tags: r, plot

I'm running an R file "practice.R" which has several plots. I'm running the file in RStudio by entering the command source("practice.R"). When I run the file, only the last plot appears for me. Is there any way I can have it so that the first plot appears, and then I can press enter so that the next plot appears and so on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the arrows (in the red circle) above the plotting area to see older plots.

[image]